# Create Dockerfile and mount azure file share on linux image

Tags: linux, azure, docker, drupal

I am trying to follow [Mount Azure File storage on Linux VMs using SMB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/mount-azure-file-storage-on-linux-using-smb), which shows how to mount azure files on a folder in Linux VM. The only difference, is I am trying to mount the share on a Linux container created using Dockerfile.

While facing several issues, I understood the need to run the container in "privileged" mode to allow me to run mount command. However so far I have been unsuccessful ,and I can't find references of docker file doing something like this.

I am trying to run this command in Docker File.

```
RUN -it --privileged  mount -t cifs filesharepath mountpath  -o vers=3.0,username=username,password=password,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino
```

However, I continuously get an error like illegal character `-t` which doesn't lead anywhere.

So first question would be, is it possible to achieve something like this from Docker File ? And if so, what are the possibilities?

Update:

The purpose of mounting is especially to mount a drupa file storing directory to an azure file share. for eg : var/sites/default/files to azure file storage. This may need solution which has been done for drupal specific implementations. If anyone with an idea , it will be helpful!

Comment: Why aren't you simply using a volume? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files

Comment: this command doesnt make any sense in a dockerfile, this command would make sense as a part of a `docker run`, perhaps?

Comment: @CSharpRocks because i want to use file share as a network file share for drupal websites and the files uploaded from the website need to go in the file share (which is mounted on the drupal files directory) . also i am not sure what this means on the page. "Be aware that if you mount a share into a container directory in which files or directories exist, these files or directories are obscured by the mount and are not accessible while the container runs." i want to mount a volume on a folder within a container.

Answer (score 4):

Feels like we need to clarify something here:

- Dockerfile is a place where you put all setup instructions. Like you want a linux machine based on ubuntu plus install several packages. Then Dockerfile is the place where to configure it. it also allows to configure exposed ports and default startup thing. Period. Mount external volume to something inside of the container - doesn't make any sense in Dockerfile because it have no idea about host system and should not.
- after you have your Dockerfile you can build your local docker image, by doing `docker build ....`. So you need Dockerfile only if you can't find public image with what you need to run.
- once you have an image yo want to run you can do `docker run` on host os with `--mount source=myvol2,target=/app` option to map host folder to container inner folder.

To summarize:

- `--mount` command can be defined during docker run command (the basic and simples way to start container from image),
- Or in docker-compose file if you are using docker compose (usually development env to have multiple containers run with configuration in one place).
- Or in deployment yaml files if you are going to use kubernetes (usually for production, where you need thing works automatically).

Answer (score 4):

I will do this via docker volumes. Its more practical to use volumes than compromising security of the containers. Volumes can be created using command line or though docker compose.

Create a docker volume via commandline

```
docker volume create \
--driver local \
--opt type=cifs \
--opt device=//MyStorageAccount.file.core.windows.net/myFileShare \
--opt o=addr=MyStorageAccount.file.core.windows.net,username=MyStorageAccount,password=*****==,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 \
--name MyVolume
```

Then mount it when you create container.

```
docker run -d  --name MyContainer  --mount source=MyVolume,target=/app  nginx:latest
```

You can also use the volume in compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - MyVolume:/app
volumes:
  MyVolume:
    external: true
```

You can create the volume within docker-compose. Do update the password field or use variables

```
version: "3"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: nginx:1.16.0
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - MyVolume:/app
volumes:
  MyVolume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "cifs"
      o: "mfsymlinks,vers=3.0,username=MyStorageAccount,password=******==,addr=MyStorageAccount.file.core.windows.net"
      device: "//MyStorageAccount.file.core.windows.net/myFileShare"
```

Comment: Running the docker volume create command on windows yeilds: Error response from daemon: create devshare: options are not supported on this platform

Comment: I tried the `docker volume create` command today in windows 10 pro with Docker desktop 4.0.1 and worked without any issues.

Comment: did you supply any driver options with the command? docker volume create works on its own for me but as soon as I provide additional options I get the error. You need to supply additonal options to use cifs.

Comment: Yes, I tried exactly same command as in my answer with all options required for attaching cifs volume. Instead of '\', you need to use '^' for multi-line commands in CMD.

Comment: I have realised my miscommunication. I'm trying this with Windows containers! Driver options aren't supported with Windows Containers only Linux containers. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: The docker volume create solution shown by @Jak worked perfectly on MacOS, I was able to create the volume and then mount it into my container allowing me to access our Azure File Share easily - thanks